# CSS file loading slowly only on certain pages

Tags: css, performance

My CSS file is loading incredibly slowly on certain pages. 
The exact same CSS file is loaded on every page so I just cannot understand the difference in speed.

**Pages with normal load speed:**

http://www.soundshelter.net/index.php

http://www.soundshelter.net/label/Smallville

**Slow page load examples:**

http://www.soundshelter.net/549053/Massimiliano_Pagliara-Major_Fun-Live_At_Robert_Johnson-House-PLAYRJC033.html

http://www.soundshelter.net/400597/Arto_Mwambe-Duster_FC-Live_At_Robert_Johnson-House-.html

http://www.soundshelter.net/548692/Russ_Gabriel-In_The_Van_EP-We_Play_House-House-WPH022.html

Comment: I don't see the slow loading of CSS you report. Perhaps it's your browser? It will help if you create valid HTML, see: http://validator.w3.org

Comment: I can confirm that CSS loads immediately with the content..

Answer (score 1):

If you have large CSS document, then it is good practice to minify if. It will speed up downloading CSS file.

http://cssminifier.com/

http://www.minifycss.com/